# Defining hooks within (php)classes?

Tags: hooks, options

I have been trying to write a reusable modular options class and I am stuck at this specific point.

How do i define hooks within php classes?

### Try 1 :

```
class super_options {
     // ..........................

       function render_options_page ()
       {
            //....................

                $this->top_page_hook();
            //....................
        } 

     // ..........................

        function top_page_hook() {
             do_action( array( &$this, 'top_page_hook') );
        }

}
```

and when hooking to the above,
     add_action( array( &$plugs, 'top_page_hook' ), 'stuff_for_top_hook' );

This doesn't work.

### Try 2 :

- Replacing the `$this->top_page_hook();`, with `do_action( 'top_page_hook' );`
- Calling `add_action( 'top_page_hook', 'stuff_for_top_hook' );`
- Works, but the class loses its reusability.

So how do i take care of this? Please share your wisdom. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hook can only be identified by string. So the only option to have dynamic hook is is use some variable(s) in its name:

```
do_action( $some_string_variable . '_top_page_hook' );
```

Depending on what you are trying to do this can be something meaningful (like prefix, defined by configuration) or something randomly generated to be unique ID (not so common).

Comment: Exactly. You only pass in the class when you call `add_action()` so you can avoid name collisions with function names.  `do_action()` just takes the string name for the action (well, and additional variables you're passing along, but that's beyond the scope of your question).

Comment: That works perfectly. I already have a property `$this->page_prefix`, so `$this->page_prefix . '_top_page_hook'` does the job. Thanks a lot.